# How get product IDs of root category and subcategory under root category programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, category, product-list, resource-model

I want to get all product IDs of a root category and subcategory programmatically, when I click the root category. How can I get product IDs of both categories together under root category?

Comment: Assign the all product from backend to the root category it will automatically display at front side when you open this root category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin panel set `yes` the value for `Is Anchor`.

> Steps:
>
> Go to Catalog > Manage Categories and set `Is Anchor` to `Yes`.
>
> Re-index your catalog product index

[image]